# When to take maintenance exam? DEV

Tags: dev401

I got certified sometime in February 2014 for as a dev. I also received an email from salesforce saying to taker a maintenance exam.

**We recommend that you complete the online exam by July 18, 2014, prior to the next release (Summer ‘14).**

At what point will I ABSOLUTELY have to take a maintenance exam before I lose my certification? I was told I can be 2 releases behind. Can someone please explain to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the deadlines here for each release:
http://certification.salesforce.com/schedules

Answer (score 2):

You can be two behind.  As soon as the third maintenance exam is released, you lose your accreditation.

This happened to me a few years back when I was slack and didnt keep up to date.

They are not hard and dont take too much time so it is worth keeping up to date.

Good luck!